# generating radical of an ideal with small degree polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Say $f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n$ are a finite set of polynomials in $M$ variables $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_M$ over a field $k$. Say each $f_i$ has total degree at most $D$. If $I$ the ideal generated by the $f_\alpha$ and $J$ is the radical $\sqrt{I}$ of $I$, is $J$ also generated by polynomials of total degree at most $D$? The person who asked me this was only interested in the case where $k$ was the real numbers but it seems to be an interesting question in general.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/212298/degrees-of-generators-of-radical-ideals

Comment: Aah, thanks for this. I did look through the site before I posted but I missed this one. Someone else asked me the question, perhaps this explains it.